No audio on 20.04
I've been having problems with audio on and off.
I resolved it initially by adding "options snd-hda-intel model=auto" to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf.

It worked for some time and then it stopped working while listening to audio.
  
sudo dmesg gives me an error
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: no codecs found!

sudo pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
gives me an error
[pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process

Devices:
-Precision-M6800:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [1028:05cd]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Dell 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [1028:05cd]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:0e0a] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Dell GK104 HDMI Audio Controller [1028:15cd]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

List of devices under aplay:
-Precision-M6800:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

cat /proc/asound/cards gives me
-Precision-M6800:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [HDMI ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7a34000 irq 41
1 [PCH ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7a30000 irq 38
2 [NVidia ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
HDA NVidia at 0xf5080000 irq 17

As far as I understand HDA Intel PCH doesnt show under aplay
I've tried a lot of things but none seem to work or work for a short period.

20.04 is four years old. Was your device built later than that? If so, switching to a recent version of Ubuntu like 24.04 might help.

I was on 22.04 when audio problems started . Installing 24.04 didn't solve the problem ,only on 20.04 I got audio. My laptop is from 2013. The problem seems to be with ALSA.
